# SQL query many to many(four tables)

Tags: sql-server, many-to-many

## Tables

**product**: id, price
**productattribute**:id, productid, attributeid
**attributes**: id, value, attributetypeid
**attributetype**:id, name

## Query

```
select p.Name, p.Price, att.Id, att.Value, at.Id, at.Name
from Product p
inner join ProductAttribute pa on pa.ProductId = p.Id
inner join Attributes att on att.Id = pa.AttributeId
inner join AttributeType at on att.AttributeTypeId = at.Id
```

## Result

```
Name              Price    Id    Value     Id      Name
Slr camera           90     1    White      1      Color   
digital camera       98     2    Black      1      Color    
Slr camera           90     4    big        2      Size
digital camera       98     5    medium     2      Size
```

Now I want to retrieve products by filtering attributesid ie attributesid=1(which is white) and doing so must filter only the color attributetype not the size. What I mean is it should retrieve three rows now: rows with Color - White, Size - big and Size - medium.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what your question is and the problems you're facing. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `where` clause to allow non-color attributes and color attributes if they're white:

```
where  at.AttributeTypeId <> 1 -- Non-color attribute
       or at.AttributeTypeId = 1 and att.Id = 1 -- White color
```

Comment: but what if i also wanna filter non-color attribute . say now both white and medium(size-attributetype).

Comment: @Abdimar but what if i also wanna filter non-color attribute . say now both white and medium(size-attributetype). i mean it can go on with any combination of attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.Name,p.Price,att.Id,att.Value,at.Id,at.Name from Product p
inner join ProductAttribute pa on pa.ProductId=p.Id
inner join Attributes att on att.Id=pa.AttributeId
inner join AttributeType at on att.AttributeTypeId=at.Id
where att.id = 1 or (at.AttributeTypeId = 1 and att.Id = 1 );
```

Comment: your  query it retrieve only on row

Answer (score 0):

May be the query bellow would be useful for you:

```
SELECT
  p.Name,
  p.Price,
  att.Id,
  att.Value,
  at.Id,
  at.Name 
FROM
  Product p, ProductAttribute pa, Attributes att, AttributeType at
WHERE pa.ProductId=p.Id
  AND att.Id=pa.AttributeId 
  AND att.AttributeTypeId=at.Id
  AND (  at.Id <> 1
      OR at.Id = 1 AND att.value = 'White')
```

Comment: but what if i wanna filter both white n medium. i mean it can go on with any combination of attributes.